# Matching 2 enums

Tags: java, typescript, enums

#### Overview

I have two enums:

1. `FrontEnum`:

   ```js
   FrontEnum {
       HIGH = 'The highest of hights',
       MEDIUM = 'The medium height',
       LOW = 'No hight',
   }
   ```
2. `BackEndEnum`:

   ```java
   public enum BackEndEnum {
       HIGH_ASDF(12),
       MEDIUM_ASDF(23),
       LOW_ASDF(34),
   }
   ```

- The first one is exposed to the user as labels of checkboxes.
- I can't modify those enums.
- Frontend: Angular, Backend: Spring Boot

#### The question

Let's say the user checks the *'The medium height'* checkbox.

**How should I send to the backend the key (MEDIUM) of this enum's value to match the key of the backend enum (MEDIUM_ASDF)** so the backend can later resolve it as '23' and proceed further?

Comment: at least you can keep the same name of enum not values and define the getter function for backend enum.  let val = BackEndEnum[BackEndEnum.MEDIUM] else you will end up syncing at multiple places.

Comment: unfortunately i can't modify them at all ;/

Comment: Added an ans in typescript, please check

Comment: How you consume FrontEnum's data from FrontEnd in BackEnd means java side ? Are you using any framework ?

Comment: Through rest api with Spring Boot. Should've pointed it out at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a backend enum like this to solve this problem,

```
public enum BackEndEnum {
    HIGH_ASDF(12, "The highest of heights"),
    MEDIUM_ASDF(23, "The medium height"),
    LOW_ASDF(34, "No height");
    
    private int id;
    private String value;

    BackEndEnum(final int id, final String value) {
      this.id = id;
      this.value = value;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getValue() { 
         return this.value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are sending `FrontEnum` types from the frontend and converting it to `BackEndEnum`, so use below function to convert it.

```
function getValue(frontEnum: FrontEnum): number {
    let backEndVal: number;
    switch(frontEnum){
        case FrontEnum.HIGH: 
            backEndVal = BackEndEnum.HIGH_ASDF;
            break;
         case FrontEnum.MEDIUM: 
            backEndVal = BackEndEnum.MEDIUM_ASDF;
            break;
         case FrontEnum.LOW: 
            backEndVal = BackEndEnum.LOW_ASDF;
            break;
    }

    return backEndVal;
}

console.log(getValue(FrontEnum.MEDIUM)); // 23 as output
```

Playground link: [Click here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTgexAFwKLmgbwLACgoFQASAkgOJFQC8UA5ACoAWwUjAlgObMDOyUCAM1adGybrQA0eQlACyqACIkAqrOp0mLCMAAmbSK2Ajkk6YQAyAeQDq62gDkEwriam4AvgG48eUAYBCAIYAxgDW6DroBjj4hKQUAPoAggDKCjDqAIwATG4y8kqqyWkZNNkAzHkWNsXp6uUALHhePrgCYCDByGxIUBzAyABqgQA2YMAAFAKIKFEQAFywM2gYAJSLGABGwHBQMTIjA1CbIeEgOsMjG5DbcN6xBNwA7mzIwYxTy3Or%20zKEwYFuCx4EgVpAAHTxIiLMx-P4nMIRS7qIKI85zSHkIi1GD3OFwzZwYCBUJ4-FQAFApagjEFFSyGEPcnHU5I0Yo1nojDgulFVLpMnM45EkmCuGU4FfblWayMoUEBFnC7smiopUYmU4sXkwnE0mwqDuVoyInIMBwEAstHKkb3I24PDBJDcBCHcEjBAcCb9IajcYTEGzbm82SrVaeIA)

Answer (score 0):

If you can`t change any of the mentioned enums, one possibility would be matching by its position. However, I highly recommend a more advanced solution, such as Vishal's answer. Matching by position is too weak, and risk. Any position modification will give you wrong results.

```
  private static BackEndEnum byPosition(final int pos){
    final var values = BackEndEnum.values();
    if(pos < 0 || pos > values.length){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Position");
    }
    return values[pos];
  }
```